# SQL Server + database design and non mandatory fields

Tags: database-design, sql-server

I am developing an app which allows a user to upload a maximum of 20 photos, the straight forward way is of course adding 20 columns to my database table but if the user only uploads 1 image, the remaining columns becomes redundant. Anyone can advice me on a more efficient way to design it?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a separate table for photos, set Users PK as a foreign key, add a column with the number of the uploaded photos to the Users.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos WHERE user_id = :id` before inserting new photos?

Comment: --the straight forward way is of course adding 20 columns to my database table-- That's the worst way you can do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should never use multiple columns to hold more than one of the same item.  This is bad database design and will be a major pain to use (try to write a query that will fetch and display all of a user's photos, or delete one photo, and you will see what I mean).

Another issue is that you might want to store other info about each photo--such as when it was uploaded and what format it is.  Instead of 20 columns, suddenly you might have 60 or 80 columns in your table. Ugh!

Instead, have a table of photos that is separate from the table of users.  This is linked to the user table on user ID.  You can enforce the 20 photo limit with a table constraint, or simply by checking the number of photos programmatically before you allow upload.

Table **user**:

```
Primary Key |       |       |
USER_ID     | FIRST | LAST  | ETC.
12345       | John  | Smith | ... Any other user-specific columns
```

Table **photo**:

```
Primary Key | Foreign Key |        |        |            |
PHOTO_ID    | USER_ID     | PHOTO  | FORMAT | DATE       | ETC.
13516       | 12345       | <data> | JPG    | 2013-05-01 | ... Other photo-specific columns
```

If you set the foreign key for **photo** to `on delete cascade`, a user's photos will automatically be deleted if you delete the user.

See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8268337/1919238) for info on a table constraint to limit the number of photos per user.

Getting the photos for a user uses a simple query:

```
select * from photo
    where user_id = 12345;
```

If you need photos and user information like the name, use a join:

```
select first, last, photo from photo p
   inner join user u on p.user_id = u.user_id;
```

**Update:** I do agree with Pieter B that, in most cases, you are probably better off storing the images separately in the file structure, and just making the `images` table store the file name of each image.  This will make it a lot easier to, say, display the images on a web page.  But you will also need extra code to make sure the directory stays in sync with the table--if you delete a user, you have to go manually delete all of the images.

Answer (score 2):

In general I would not store photos in binary form in a database. What I would do is store photos on disk and store the path to that photo in the database.

Other answers already showed how to create a seperate table, use that but with the references instead of the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

You add a child table

```
PhotoID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
UserID int NOT NULL -- FK to User table,
Photo varbinary(max)
```

This changes columns into rows, quite simply as per [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

There are storage benefits because you now no longer have potentially 20 BLOBS in one user row. Your user table has a lot less memory footprint for other columns.

And you can allow more then 20 photos very easily if you decide to allow more.